# boundfield.py -- render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'

Tags: django, python-3.x, leaflet, django-admin, boundfield

i see this error many times here and it seems to be different each time. 
I'm working on a geodjango app with leaflet. and i'm getting this error since i installed leaflet. 
I rode this in an other post:

> - Support for Widget.render() methods without the renderer argument is removed.

Is there any way i can fix this without having to go back to version - 2.0.8 ??

```
   Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/travel/location/15493/change/

Django Version: 3.0.4
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.gis',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'travel.apps.TravelConfig',
 'django_extensions',
 'leaflet']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
   render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
   9 :             {% for field in line %}
   10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="fieldBox{% if field.field.name %} field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %} hidden{% endif %}"{% elif field.is_checkbox %} class="checkbox-row"{% endif %}>
   11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
   12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
   14 :                     {% else %}
   15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}
   16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}
   17 :                             <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                              {{ field.field }} 
   20 :                         {% endif %}
   21 :                     {% endif %}
   22 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
   23 :                         <div class="help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
   24 :                     {% endif %}
   25 :                 </div>
   26 :             {% endfor %}
   27 :         </div>
   28 :     {% endfor %}
   29 : </fieldset>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 188, in render
    return template.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 173, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 992, in render
    return render_value_in_context(output, context)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 971, in render_value_in_context
    value = str(value)
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 373, in <lambda>
    klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 33, in __str__
    return self.as_widget()
  File "/Users/marcusbey/.local/share/virtualenvs/rb-website-fKSjEdfu/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py", line 92, in as_widget
    return widget.render(

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/travel/location/15493/change/
Exception Value: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
```

Comment: Well i end up commenting the line 92 of boundfield.py and it doesn't seem to break anything. Is there something i should worry about? :s

Answer (score 1):

Although just commenting the line 97 in the `boundfield.py` have worked, I solved this issue by navigating to the folder in which the render function was called. For instance, by adding `renderer=None` in `widgets.py` file in the django_markdown folder solved the problem.

boundfield.py

```
        return widget.render(
            name=self.html_initial_name if only_initial else self.html_name,
            value=self.value(),
            attrs=attrs,
            #renderer=self.form.renderer,
        )
```

widgets.py

```
""" Widgets for django-markdown. """
import os

from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminTextareaWidget
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from . import settings
from .utils import editor_js_initialization


class MarkdownWidget(forms.Textarea):

    """ Widget for a textarea.

    Takes two additional optional keyword arguments:

    ``markdown_set_name``
        Name for current set. Default: value of MARKDOWN_SET_NAME setting.

    ``markdown_skin``
        Name for current skin. Default: value of MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN setting.

    """

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        super(MarkdownWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        """ Render widget.

        :returns: A rendered HTML

        """
        html = super(MarkdownWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
        attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        html += editor_js_initialization("#%s" % attrs['id'])
        return mark_safe(html)

    class Media:
        css = {
            'screen': (
                os.path.join('django_markdown', 'skins', settings.MARKDOWN_EDITOR_SKIN, 'style.css'),
                os.path.join(settings.MARKDOWN_SET_PATH, settings.MARKDOWN_SET_NAME, 'style.css')
            )
        }

        js = (
            os.path.join('django_markdown', 'jquery.init.js'),
            os.path.join('django_markdown', 'jquery.markitup.js'),
            os.path.join(settings.MARKDOWN_SET_PATH, settings.MARKDOWN_SET_NAME, 'set.js')
        )


class AdminMarkdownWidget(MarkdownWidget, AdminTextareaWidget):

    """ Support markdown widget in Django Admin. """

    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before and didn't find any fix for it , but I deleted the "renderer" line in the  boundfield.py file which will be inline 92 **just delete it.**